# How to set the border-radius for a div contained by another to achieve a constant width?

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside a div, the gap between their sides is 3mm (set by padding). Now, I would like to round their borders in a visually appealing way. Setting the same radius obviously does not work.

So I thought it over, and concluded, that it would look good, if the "border", which is the part of the outer div not covered by the inner one has a constant width. This is possible only if the centers of the circles that draw the round parts of the divs are the same (concentric). Therefore, in case of a 6mm outer radius, I need 6mm - 3mm = 3mm inner radius.

My problem is that if I set it to 3, than it looks like it was thinner near the corners. But if I set it to 4mm, it looks OK.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k9L1z4or/2/

HTML:

Outer radius: 6mm

Inner radius: 3mm

CSS:

```
#outer {
  background: blue;
  padding: 3mm;
  border-radius: 6mm;
}

#inner {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20mm;
  border-radius: 3mm;
}
```

JS

```
function changeRadius() {
  const innerDiv = document.getElementById( 'inner' );
  innerDiv.style.borderRadius = innerDiv.style.borderRadius === '3mm'  ?  '4mm'  :  '3mm';
  innerDiv.innerHTML = innerDiv.innerHTML.replace( /[34]mm/, innerDiv.style.borderRadius );
}
```

You can change between the 3mm and 4mm inner radius with the button.

My question is: What causes that the 4mm appears better than the 3mm? Is there some other aspect of the question (like borders, margins) I should consider?

Comment: Is there any purpose for the parent div? If there is no specific intension for the parent div except the blue filled gap, you can achieve by removing the outer div and styling the inner div with border: 6mm solid blue;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Kirubanandan/d0qk8sm1/2/

Comment: @KirubanandanKanagaraj: Yes, it's part of a more complex system with lots of scripting, which I omitted to focus on this issue.